# Generic Props for Typescript type check

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I want to write a component which will receive components and props, and render with injecting custom props

```
type InjectProps<P> = {
  custom: string
} & P

interface Props<P> {
  component: React.ComponentType<InjectProps<P>>
  componentProps: P
}

class PropInjector<T> extends Component<Props<T>> {
  ...
  render() {
    const GivenComponent = this.props.component
    return (
      // in my case, Wrapper is needed for some reason.
      <Wrapper>
        <GivenComponent {...this.props.componentProps} custom="props" />
      <Wrapper />
    )
  }
}
```

When I test with `Input` which props are defined like this,

```
interface InputProps {
  custom: string
  value: string
  onChange(value: string): void
}
class Input extends Component<InputProps> { ... }
```

I thought typescript could infer and typecheck on this code under, but it didn't throw any errors.

```
render() {
  return (
    // should throw error about not existing Input's required props like value, onChange ....
    // But no error
    <PropInjector component={Input} componentProps={{}} />
  )
}
```

How can i make Typescript to infer `P`, and do some typecheck on componentProps with `P` when using `PropInjector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible with TypeScript at the moment. In your final `render()` method, you are not providing a generic value to `PropInjector`. Therefore TypeScript has no idea what `T` is supposed to be inside `PropInjector`.

A workaround is to define an intermediate component like this:

```
class InputPropInjector extends PropInjector<InputProps> { }

class Input extends Component<InputProps> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <InputPropInjector component={Input} componentProps={{}} />
        );
    }
}
```

There has been a good bit of [discussion about this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6395) so hopefully a better solution will be available in future.

Comment: Thanks! If generic doesn't work with JSX then I have to give up typing those components. But that issue you mentioned has been set to milestone for TS2.9! I will wait and wait for release of that version :D